# Similar code in NSOUP

Tags: java, .net

I have a code in Jsoup

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication17 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

  String str=/* url */;
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Elements paragraphs = doc.select("td");
  List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Element p : paragraphs) 
  {
      text.add(p.text());
  }
  String name[] = new String[1000];
  for(int i=0,j=0;i<100;i++)
  {
      name[i]=text.get(i);
      System.out.println(name[i]);
  }

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication17.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
  }
}
```

What is the equilivalent NSOUP ie. the similar .NET code...
If NSOUP is not the best option for similar use in .net then what should be used... ??

Comment: ```Please can anybody convert it into NSOUP``` NO. Read the rules http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: By looking at the source code, the usage seems exactly the same: http://nsoup.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NSoup/NSoup.cs
Did you even try it?